# Heroku PHP app crash bash: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2: No such file or directory

Tags: php, heroku, codeigniter-2

I'm not very good with Heroku setup

I'm trying to put online an app in PHP (with Code Igniter) but it doesn't work well. Here is the error :

```
Heroku PHP app crash bash: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2: No such file or directory
```

index.php is in root folder. Vendor directory also in root folder
composer made his job
In procfile :

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2
```

And in my index.php:

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');
```

In the past I used the boot.sh way, so I'm not comfortable with the new way.
I followed this tutorial 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#introduction

I think I missed something obvious. But I don't know what.
Thank you

Comment: wanted to ask, where did you write this require('vendor/autoload.php'); ??
I opened the index.php file but there doesnt seem like a place to write this

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your `composer.json` likely re-defines the `bin-dir` setting to something other than `vendor/bin`. Run `composer config bin-dir` to see what it is (or look at your `composer.json`'s `config` section, and adjust the path to `heroku-php-apache2` in your `Procfile` accordingly.

You can also just change the `Procfile` to automatically read the right value:

```
web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2
```

The notes at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#web-servers also mention this `bin-dir` caveat.

Comment: Thank you but the bin-dir is already set to :
➜  app git:(master) composer config bin-dir
vendor/bin

there is nothing more in composer than this : 
{
  "require" : {
    "rfd/imagemagick": "~1.1"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"
  }
}

Comment: And `heroku config` doesn't show a `BUILDPACK_URL`, right? If it does, you're using some other (likely third party) buildpack... so remove it and push again.

Comment: The `web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2 public/` command execution works particularly well. Even though when I executed the `composer config bin-dir` command I received `vendor/bin`, my app was repetitively crashing. But then I updated the `Procfile` with the above command and all worked like magic. This was probably because my `.gitignore` file contained `/vendor` in it, I'm not sure though. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

My solution was to add the code below to `composer.json`.

```
"require-dev": {
    "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php" : "dev-master"
}
```

Then run `composer update`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to remove your procfile and add the base composer.json

Answer (score 1):

Thanks To David, here is the answer :

You're using the legacy version of the buildpack - your app has BUILDPACK_URL set to https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php.git#legacy.
Run heroku config:unset BUILDPACK_URL and push an empty change (git commit -m "new buildpack" --allow-empty will do).

Because I Copy/pasted old vars from an old project (> 1 year) using boot.sh

There was BUILDPACK_URL which was the bad URL. No need to put it now.

Thanks dzuelke !

Answer (score 0):

In addition to following the steps exactly as described here :

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel

I had to remove .env from gitignore and also set

APP_KEY generated using

php artisan key:generate --show

to .env

in order for this to work.

Comment: For your app key I get output like `base64:XXXXXXXXXX=`. Do you include the "base64:" portion in you .env file?

Comment: @ConnorLeech Yes, you do include the "base64:" portion. This feature lets us store an application key with special characters inside the _.env_ file. Laravel decodes it when reading the value of the key.