# Laravel 5 deploy to heroku: /bin/sh: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, composer-php, heroku-toolbelt

I generated a new Laravel application and deployed it to heroku using the Heroku PHP Buildpack.

I defined my **Procfile** as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28199025/2031033):

```
web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2
```

But when I deploy the application or run `heroku local` the error persists.

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php
$ heroku local                   
 ▸    heroku-cli: update available from 6.13.13 to 6.14.24-72dfccf
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
12:42:33 PM web.1 |  /bin/sh: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2: No such file or directory
12:42:33 PM web.1 Exited with exit code 127
```

Why is heroku-php-apache2 undefined and how do I deploy my Laravel application to Heroku?

Comment: What is the actual error you see when deploying to Heroku? For `heroku local` to work, you need to install the Heroku BuildPack package: `composer require --dev "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php:*"`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015139/laravel-5-heroku-local-doesnt-work).

Comment: Okay cool. When I add that I get local errors related to Apache: `This program requires Apache 2.4.10 or newer with mod_proxy and mod_proxy_fcgi enabled; check your 'httpd' command.`

Comment: I'm sure you already understand that you'll need to make sure Apache is installed and appropriately configured on your local machine to use the `heroku local` command. You may prefer Laravel's `php artisan serve` as an alternative local webserver. This doesn't solve the original issue. Are you seeing the same error when you deploy to Heroku? What command do you use to deploy?

Comment: Yeah I'm going to use `php artisan serve` locally like normal and deploy to heroku. Not a big deal to not use heroku local rn